# How do I add apache commons math into VSCode

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I want to add Apache Commons Math library so I can import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.NormalDistribution; since it is not in the the java i have on VSCode. I think the file I need to download is here https://commons.apache.org/math/download_math.cgi but I dont know how to integrate it into VSCode I am on a macbook.

Comment: are you using a build system like Maven or Gradle?

Answer (score 0):

Add a dependency by clicking on the plus sign to the right in Project Management.

[image]

*https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-project#_dependency-management*